# Android instant apps feature plugin not found

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Gradle sync failed: Plugin with id 'com.android.feature' not found.

Please help me with the solution. I have followed the google docs regarding the environment setup for Instant apps. Please check the set up guide here : [Set up your environment for Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

you have to update the android gradle plugin in your build.gradle file :

```
dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
}
```

and it will works

Answer (score 0):

Try this..change to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

if you are using stable android studio