# Plugin with id 'com.android.feature' not found. Android

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

this might be a duplicate question but I'm seriously stuck trying to create an instant app using a new project.

Requirements for instant app in build.gradle file:

1. apply plugin: `'com.android.feature'`
2. baseFeature = true
3. remove = applicationId `"com.example.instantapptest"`

The problem occur "Plugin with id 'com.android.feature' not found."

Error Msg

[image: Error Msg]

SDK installed

[image: SDK installed]

these are my findings [this](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47037184/plugin-with-id-com-android-feature-not-found) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367847/android-instant-apps-feature-plugin-not-found), below is what I have and error still persist :

Classpath =

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
```

my all projects =

```
allprojects {
repositories {

    jcenter()
    google()
   }
}
```

Much help appreciated :)

Answer (score 7):

kindly refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/feature-module-migration)

old plugin: `com.android.feature`

changed to

new plugin: `com.android.dynamic-feature`